# How to open external pdf in Android with Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am working on an application, and I am facing a problem with Ionic1 , and it concerns opening a .PDF from an external URL in Android with Ionic.
I tried many solutions given in this site and other sites but in vain.
this is an example of what I have tried:

in .html file:

```
<a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.xxx.pdf', '_system', 'location=yes')">
```

in .js file:

```
var ref = window.open('http://www.xxx.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

can you suggest other solutions please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [cordova inapp browser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser).

you can replace all window.open by inappBrowser;

```
window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
```

or you can just use:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://linktopdf.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

or if you use ngCordova, you can use $cordovaInAppBrowser,

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://www.xxx.pdf', '_blank', options)
```

take a look here: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, I tried to apply cordova.InAppBrowser but it generates this error : cordova is not definded , however I am installing the ngCordova and I make it as dependency module.

Comment: try with window.cordova, FYI cordova is defined only in app by importing the cordova.js file, you can check it by if (window.cordova)